# Azure VM cannot connect to AWS s3

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was testing a web application that is normally deployed on an AWS linux VM in an Azure VM.
The (java) application accesses AWS s3 for some storage features and lists objects in an AWS s3 bucket. 
Running the application in an Azure VM the list was empty.

suspecting connectivity issues, I installed the AWS CLI on the Azure VM, configured keys, and ran:

```
$ aws s3 ls
```

This resulted in

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-east.amazonaws.com/"
```

Confirming my suspicions.

Checking the application stack trace for essentially the application's "listObjects" request shows

```
Request: http://azuredev.gpo.epacube.com/dps/job/listprojects raised com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: A2494E7A540B5B20), S3 Extended Request ID: 6+Nv1AtCTe0xz3i7Ra5lrmdEdxiIfXgxYapY9KbomblhYL4Q85L3iTLchpQcwRnixyE5El0WKwM=
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: A2494E7A540B5B20), S3 Extended Request ID: 6+Nv1AtCTe0xz3i7Ra5lrmdEdxiIfXgxYapY9KbomblhYL4Q85L3iTLchpQcwRnixyE5El0WKwM=
```

The exact same code works when run from CENTos on AWS, but when run on Ubuntu 13.04 on Azure it fails.

Why might I be getting the invalid date error?
How do I modify the Azure VM setup so the AWS s3 connections succeed?

Comment: Azure doesn't have any outbound firewall configured, and nothing that would block resolution of aws domain names from an Azure VM. And... for the record, I get the identical error when running `aws s3 ls` from my local dev machine (I just tried). I suspect this is something other than an Azure-related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a mix of JDK8 and an older version of the aws-sdk-java  dependency on joda-time. Upgrading the joda-time dependency to version 2.8.1 fixed this.

Found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/484)

Answer (score 2):

**Your region is wrong.**

`https://s3.us-east.amazonaws.com/` is not a valid endpoint. You possibly configured a region as `us-east` when it should be `us-east-1`.

I could reproduce the problem by specifying an incorrect endpoint:

This works:

```
$ aws s3 ls --region us-east-1
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ aws s3 ls --region us-east

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-east.amazonaws.com/"
```

For a full list of endpoints, see: [Regions and Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Comment: thanks, running reconfigure with us-east-1 fixed "aws s3 ls" but not the application's list objects invocation. Definitely worth an upvote though.